# How to format alphanumeric categorical data for input into Neural Network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently working on an artificial intelligence project where the inputs consist of a fixed-length vector of letters, either A, B, C, or D. I'd like to be able to input what letter exists at each position in the vector into the Neural Network. For example, at each position, have an array such that the letter at that position has a 1 in the corresponding input array, while all other positions in the array are 0. For example, if the letter in the tenth position of the letter vector is A, the "input vector" for the input neuron would be something like this:

```
[A B C D]
[1 0 0 0]
```

Of course, this could originate from a letter vector like this:

```
[A B C D D B A A B C A A]
```

However, input neurons cannot take vectors as inputs. Therefore, what is the best way to format this input for input into a neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is called one-hot-encoding. If you perform this operation on your example `[A B C D]` you will get this:

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
```

Where the first column indicates whether it is an `A`, the second wether its a `B` and so on.

You can't insert vectors into a single input of the NN, but instead of having only 4 inputs you can reshape the encoder matrix and have 16 inputs instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help--I should have called it one-hot encoding in my original post. Is this the only way to input this kind of "categorical" data into a neural network?

Comment: Not the only one, but probably the most used one since it has certain advantages (it for example does not put more weight on some elements than on others like ordinal encoding). Here's some more information: https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159

Comment: Thanks for the help!